# Wrongfully tagged questions tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

Many times I see questions which are wrongfully tagged, but I don't have the slightest clue about what tags they should be.

Generally by people who have absolutely no idea what the topic they tagging is about (common example is set-theory tags for things that are not even related to elementary set theory, but rather combinatorics and such).

Should we have a tag for wrongfully tagged questions, so the more experienced users could follow and properly retag the questions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A "wrongfully tagged" tag would be a meta-tag, which is generally discouraged.

If you do notice certain users consistently misapplying tags, please bring it to the attention of the moderators.

Otherwise you can leave a comment to the question. Sometimes the "more experienced users" do not necessarily notice the bad tags. By leaving a comment you make it more likely that they will see that the tags should be changed and change it.

Answer (score 3):

No, please *don't* create a meta tag for this as they are explicitly disallowed.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Instead, the proper thing to do is simply click the "flag" link to flag it for moderator attention and indicate you think it's mistagged.

(and Willie's advice of leaving a comment is also a good strategy)

Comment: Somewhat tangential, but can the tag [tag-removed] please be killed?

Comment: @isaac certainly, it is done

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a possibility how to bring attention of other users to questions which have incorrect tag would be mentioning it in [tagging chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/3740/tagging) or [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics) (or both).

Of course, it might still go unnoticed and even if some people see it, that does not necessarily mean that somebody will be able to suggest a better tag. But at least it could improve the chances.

(See also [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4437/could-chatrooms-serve-as-noticeboards/4439#4439) for some details on the creation of this room.)